# Use composite key as a foreign key

Tags: java, jpa

How to use a composite key as foreign key in table using JPA.

Say, I have a table u with a,b as composite key. There are other fields though.
There is another table, say V, in which  a will be a foreign key.

Comment: V should have two columns to reference U.a and U.b. A single column can't be a foreign key to two columns of another table.

Comment: Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323751/jpa-hibernate-composite-foreign-key-mapping?rq=1). It might help

Comment: if You are using Hibernate then refer this
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-composite

Answer (score 0):

Use an `@IdClass` or an `@EmbeddedId`.

Check out http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#JPA_2.0 and [Which annotation should I use: @IdClass or @EmbeddedId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212350/which-annotation-should-i-use-idclass-or-embeddedid).

Comment: Can we use a part of composite key as a foreign key?