# How to map a composite key with JPA and Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, composite-key

In this code, how to generate a Java class for the composite key (how to composite key in hibernate):

```
create table Time (
     levelStation int(15) not null,
     src varchar(100) not null,
     dst varchar(100) not null,
     distance int(15) not null,
     price int(15) not null,
     confPathID int(15) not null,
     constraint ConfPath_fk foreign key(confPathID) references ConfPath(confPathID),
     primary key (levelStation, confPathID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562746/jpa-entity-design-problem/2563009#2563009

Comment: A really good set of examples: https://vladmihalcea.com/2016/08/01/the-best-way-to-map-a-composite-primary-key-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Answer (score 475):

To map a composite key, you can use the `EmbeddedId` **or** the `IdClass` annotations. I know this question is not strictly about JPA but the rules defined by the specification also applies. So here they are:

> #### 2.1.4 Primary Keys and Entity Identity
>
> ...
>
> A composite primary key must
>   correspond to either a single
>   persistent field or property or to a
>   set of such fields or properties as
>   described below. A primary key class
>   must be defined to represent a
>   composite primary key. Composite
>   primary keys typically arise when
>   mapping from legacy databases when the
>   database key is comprised of several
>   columns. **The `EmbeddedId` and
>   `IdClass` annotations are used to
>   denote composite primary keys.** See
>   sections 9.1.14 and 9.1.15.
>
> ...
>
> The following rules apply for
>   composite primary keys:
>
> - **The primary key class must be public and must have a public no-arg
>     constructor.**
> - If property-based access is used, the properties of the primary key
>     class must be public or protected.
> - **The primary key class must be `serializable`.**
> - **The primary key class
>     must define `equals` and `hashCode`
>     methods.** The semantics of value
>     equality for these methods must be
>     consistent with the database equality
>     for the database types to which the
>     key is mapped.
> - A composite primary key must either be represented and mapped as an
>     embeddable class (see Section 9.1.14,
>     “EmbeddedId Annotation”) or must be
>     represented and mapped to multiple
>     fields or properties of the entity
>     class (see Section 9.1.15, “IdClass
>     Annotation”).
> - If the composite primary key class is mapped to multiple fields or
>     properties of the entity class, the
>     names of primary key fields or
>     properties in the primary key class
>     and those of the entity class must
>     correspond and their types must be the
>     same.

#### With an `IdClass`

The class for the composite primary key could look like (could be a static inner class):

```
public class TimePK implements Serializable {
    protected Integer levelStation;
    protected Integer confPathID;

    public TimePK() {}

    public TimePK(Integer levelStation, Integer confPathID) {
        this.levelStation = levelStation;
        this.confPathID = confPathID;
    }
    // equals, hashCode
}
```

And the entity:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(TimePK.class)
class Time implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Integer levelStation;
    @Id
    private Integer confPathID;

    private String src;
    private String dst;
    private Integer distance;
    private Integer price;

    // getters, setters
}
```

The `IdClass` annotation maps multiple fields to the table PK.

#### With `EmbeddedId`

The class for the composite primary key could look like (could be a static inner class):

```
@Embeddable
public class TimePK implements Serializable {
    protected Integer levelStation;
    protected Integer confPathID;

    public TimePK() {}

    public TimePK(Integer levelStation, Integer confPathID) {
        this.levelStation = levelStation;
        this.confPathID = confPathID;
    }
    // equals, hashCode
}
```

And the entity:

```
@Entity
class Time implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private TimePK timePK;

    private String src;
    private String dst;
    private Integer distance;
    private Integer price;

    //...
}
```

The `@EmbeddedId` annotation maps a PK class to table PK.

#### Differences:

- From the physical model point of view, there are no differences
- `@EmbeddedId` somehow communicates more clearly that the key is a composite key and IMO makes sense *when the combined pk is either a meaningful entity itself or it reused in your code*.
- `@IdClass` *is useful to specify that some combination of fields is unique but these do not have a special meaning*.

They also affect the way you write queries (making them more or less verbose):

- with `IdClass`

  ```
  select t.levelStation from Time t
  ```
- with `EmbeddedId`

  ```
  select t.timePK.levelStation from Time t
  ```

#### References

- JPA 1.0 specification

  - Section 2.1.4 "Primary Keys and Entity Identity"
  - Section 9.1.14 "EmbeddedId Annotation"
  - Section 9.1.15 "IdClass Annotation"

Comment: There is also a Hibernate-specific solution: Map multiple properties as @Id properties _without_ declaring an external class to be the identifier type (and use the IdClass annotation). See [5.1.2.1. Composite identifier](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#mapping-declaration-id) in the Hibernate manual.

Comment: Could you take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29976363/hibernate-generatedvalue-in-embedded-always-null) please? I am having troubles with a composite primary key since the member field `id` is always `null` and does not get generated :/

Comment: Could please put an example with a getter and setter as I am having difficulty seeing where they come into play in either case. Especially the IdClass example. thanks. Oh and including column names, thanks.

Comment: though hibernate specific solution is deprecated.

Comment: From the [Hibernate Annotations docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-identifier), about `@IdClass`: "It has been inherited from the dark ages of EJB 2 for backward compatibilities and we recommend you not to use it (for simplicity sake)."

Comment: So the repository signature in this case would be `public interface TimeRepository extends JpaRepository<Time, TimePK>`, correct?

Comment: Annotating multiple fields as @Id didn't work for me.  I got nullpointer errors and collisions.

Answer (score 56):

You need to use [`@EmbeddedId`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-mapping-identifier):

```
@Entity
class Time {
    @EmbeddedId
    TimeId id;

    String src;
    String dst;
    Integer distance;
    Integer price;
}

@Embeddable
class TimeId implements Serializable {
    Integer levelStation;
    Integer confPathID;
}
```

Comment: @Thierry-DimitriRoy how could I assign the timeId.levelStation and timeId.confPathID. Could you provide an example please?

Comment: @Thierry-DimitriRoy Can the primary class not be a static inner class of the entity class?

Comment: Yes, it could be

Answer (score 28):

Assuming you have the following database tables:

[image: Database tables]

First, you need to create the `@Embeddable` holding the composite identifier:

```
@Embeddable
public class EmployeeId implements Serializable {
 
    @Column(name = "company_id")
    private Long companyId;
 
    @Column(name = "employee_number")
    private Long employeeNumber;
 
    public EmployeeId() {
    }
 
    public EmployeeId(Long companyId, Long employeeId) {
        this.companyId = companyId;
        this.employeeNumber = employeeId;
    }
 
    public Long getCompanyId() {
        return companyId;
    }
 
    public Long getEmployeeNumber() {
        return employeeNumber;
    }
 
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof EmployeeId)) return false;
        EmployeeId that = (EmployeeId) o;
        return Objects.equals(getCompanyId(), that.getCompanyId()) &&
                Objects.equals(getEmployeeNumber(), that.getEmployeeNumber());
    }
 
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getCompanyId(), getEmployeeNumber());
    }
}
```

With this in place, we can map the `Employee` entity which uses the composite identifier by annotating it with `@EmbeddedId`:

```
@Entity(name = "Employee")
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {
 
    @EmbeddedId
    private EmployeeId id;
 
    private String name;
 
    public EmployeeId getId() {
        return id;
    }
 
    public void setId(EmployeeId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
 
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
 
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

The `Phone` entity which has a `@ManyToOne` association to `Employee`, needs to reference the composite identifier from the parent class via two `@JoinColumn`mappings:

```
@Entity(name = "Phone")
@Table(name = "phone")
public class Phone {
 
    @Id
    @Column(name = "`number`")
    private String number;
 
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(
            name = "company_id",
            referencedColumnName = "company_id"),
        @JoinColumn(
            name = "employee_number",
            referencedColumnName = "employee_number")
    })
    private Employee employee;
 
    public Employee getEmployee() {
        return employee;
    }
 
    public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }
 
    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
 
    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a tool which can generate EmployeeId from db schema?

Comment: Try Hibernate Tools. It has a Reverse engineering tool for that.

Comment: Would be great for such examples to consider different values for both `name` and `referencedColumnName` properties of the `JoinColumn` annotation as well as different names of tables' columns. Otherwise, it is not (quickly) clear the mapping part between them.

Comment: There is also one more interesting case, when the actual ID field/property is declared into one of entity's super classes, then you will face the following issue:
- https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16501

Answer (score 8):

**The primary key class must define equals and hashCode methods**

1. When implementing equals you should **use instanceof** to allow comparing with subclasses. If Hibernate lazy loads a one to one or many to one relation, you will have a proxy for the class instead of the plain class. A proxy is a subclass. Comparing the class names would fail.
   More technically: You should follow the Liskows Substitution Principle and ignore symmetricity.
2. The next pitfall is using something like **name.equals(that.name)** instead of **name.equals(that.getName())**. The first will fail, if that is a proxy.

http://www.laliluna.de/jpa-hibernate-guide/ch06s06.html

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you are doing this from scratch. Try using available reverse engineering tools like Netbeans Entities from Database to at least get the basics automated (like embedded ids). This can become a huge headache if you have many tables. I suggest avoid reinventing the wheel and use as many tools available as possible to reduce coding to the minimum and most important part, what you intent to do.

Answer (score 5):

Let's take a simple example. Let's say two tables named `test` and `customer` are there described as:

```sql
create table test(
  test_id int(11) not null auto_increment,
  primary key(test_id));

create table customer(
  customer_id int(11) not null auto_increment,
  name varchar(50) not null,
  primary key(customer_id));
```

One more table is there which keeps the track of `test`s and `customer`:

```sql
create table tests_purchased(
  customer_id int(11) not null,
  test_id int(11) not null,
  created_date datetime not null,
  primary key(customer_id, test_id));
```

We can see that in the table `tests_purchased` the primary key is a composite key, so we will use the `<composite-id ...>...</composite-id>` tag in the `hbm.xml` mapping file. So the `PurchasedTest.hbm.xml` will look like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
  "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
  "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="entities.PurchasedTest" table="tests_purchased">

    <composite-id name="purchasedTestId">
      <key-property name="testId" column="TEST_ID" />
      <key-property name="customerId" column="CUSTOMER_ID" />
    </composite-id>

    <property name="purchaseDate" type="timestamp">
      <column name="created_date" />
    </property>

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

But it doesn't end here. In Hibernate we use session.load (`entityClass`, `id_type_object`) to find and load the entity using primary key. In case of composite keys, the ID object should be a separate ID class (in above case a `PurchasedTestId` class) **which just declares the primary key attributes like below**:

```java
import java.io.Serializable;

public class PurchasedTestId implements Serializable {
  private Long testId;
  private Long customerId;

  // an easy initializing constructor
  public PurchasedTestId(Long testId, Long customerId) {
    this.testId = testId;
    this.customerId = customerId;
  }

  public Long getTestId() {
    return testId;
  }

  public void setTestId(Long testId) {
    this.testId = testId;
  }

  public Long getCustomerId() {
    return customerId;
  }

  public void setCustomerId(Long customerId) {
    this.customerId = customerId;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object arg0) {
    if(arg0 == null) return false;
    if(!(arg0 instanceof PurchasedTestId)) return false;
    PurchasedTestId arg1 = (PurchasedTestId) arg0;
    return (this.testId.longValue() == arg1.getTestId().longValue()) &&
           (this.customerId.longValue() == arg1.getCustomerId().longValue());
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    int hsCode;
    hsCode = testId.hashCode();
    hsCode = 19 * hsCode+ customerId.hashCode();
    return hsCode;
  }
}
```

Important point is that we also implement the two functions `hashCode()` and `equals()` as Hibernate relies on them.

Answer (score 3):

> Using hbm.xml

```
    <composite-id>

        <!--<key-many-to-one name="productId" class="databaselayer.users.UserDB" column="user_name"/>-->
        <key-property name="productId" column="PRODUCT_Product_ID" type="int"/>
        <key-property name="categoryId" column="categories_id" type="int" />
    </composite-id>
```

> Using Annotation

Composite Key Class

```
public  class PK implements Serializable{
    private int PRODUCT_Product_ID ;    
    private int categories_id ;

    public PK(int productId, int categoryId) {
        this.PRODUCT_Product_ID = productId;
        this.categories_id = categoryId;
    }

    public int getPRODUCT_Product_ID() {
        return PRODUCT_Product_ID;
    }

    public void setPRODUCT_Product_ID(int PRODUCT_Product_ID) {
        this.PRODUCT_Product_ID = PRODUCT_Product_ID;
    }

    public int getCategories_id() {
        return categories_id;
    }

    public void setCategories_id(int categories_id) {
        this.categories_id = categories_id;
    }

    private PK() { }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if ( this == o ) {
            return true;
        }

        if ( o == null || getClass() != o.getClass() ) {
            return false;
        }

        PK pk = (PK) o;
        return Objects.equals(PRODUCT_Product_ID, pk.PRODUCT_Product_ID ) &&
                Objects.equals(categories_id, pk.categories_id );
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(PRODUCT_Product_ID, categories_id );
    }
}
```

Entity Class

```
@Entity(name = "product_category")
@IdClass( PK.class )
public  class ProductCategory implements Serializable {
    @Id    
    private int PRODUCT_Product_ID ;   

    @Id 
    private int categories_id ;

    public ProductCategory(int productId, int categoryId) {
        this.PRODUCT_Product_ID = productId ;
        this.categories_id = categoryId;
    }

    public ProductCategory() { }

    public int getPRODUCT_Product_ID() {
        return PRODUCT_Product_ID;
    }

    public void setPRODUCT_Product_ID(int PRODUCT_Product_ID) {
        this.PRODUCT_Product_ID = PRODUCT_Product_ID;
    }

    public int getCategories_id() {
        return categories_id;
    }

    public void setCategories_id(int categories_id) {
        this.categories_id = categories_id;
    }

    public void setId(PK id) {
        this.PRODUCT_Product_ID = id.getPRODUCT_Product_ID();
        this.categories_id = id.getCategories_id();
    }

    public PK getId() {
        return new PK(
            PRODUCT_Product_ID,
            categories_id
        );
    }    
}
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense , He need the primary key

Comment: in title he says composite key, which doesn't have to be primary

Comment: please check what he written sql  **primary key (levelStation, confPathID)**

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to map is as a Map of composite elements in the ConfPath table.

This mapping would benefit from an index on (ConfPathID,levelStation) though.

```
public class ConfPath {
    private Map<Long,Time> timeForLevelStation = new HashMap<Long,Time>();

    public Time getTime(long levelStation) {
        return timeForLevelStation.get(levelStation);
    }

    public void putTime(long levelStation, Time newValue) {
        timeForLevelStation.put(levelStation, newValue);
    }
}

public class Time {
    String src;
    String dst;
    long distance;
    long price;

    public long getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    public void setDistance(long distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }

    public String getDst() {
        return dst;
    }

    public void setDst(String dst) {
        this.dst = dst;
    }

    public long getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(long price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getSrc() {
        return src;
    }

    public void setSrc(String src) {
        this.src = src;
    }
}
```

Mapping:

```
<class name="ConfPath" table="ConfPath">
    <id column="ID" name="id">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <map cascade="all-delete-orphan" name="values" table="example"
            lazy="extra">
        <key column="ConfPathID"/>
        <map-key type="long" column="levelStation"/>
        <composite-element class="Time">
            <property name="src" column="src" type="string" length="100"/>
            <property name="dst" column="dst" type="string" length="100"/>
            <property name="distance" column="distance"/>
            <property name="price" column="price"/>
        </composite-element>
    </map>
</class>
```