# Hibernate Composite Key: foreign key has wrong number of columns

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa, foreign-keys

I am new to Hibernate and JPA and am having difficulty setting up a composite key as defined below:

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = Entity.TABLE) 
@IdClass(EntityPK.class) 
public class MyEntity extends Entity {

        @CollectionOfElements
        @JoinTable(name="items",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="items"))
        private List<String> items;

        @Id
        private Type type;

        @Id
        private Level level;
   // plus standard constructors/getters/setters
}


public class EntityPK implements Serializable {

    private Type type;

    private Level level;

   // plus standard constructors/getters/setters
}
```

When I run my dbunit tests I get the following error:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering com.tnt.sech.domain.management.ReasonList from com.tnt.sech.domain.management.ReasonList has the wrong number of column. should be 2

Please post if you can see where I'm going wrong!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, the problem is that you can't use complex types such a `Type` and `Level` (not sure what they are) as field or property of your composite key. From the JPA specification:

> #### 2.1.4 Primary Keys and Entity Identity
>
> ...
>
> The primary key (or field or property
>   of a composite primary key) should be
>   one of the following types: **any Java
>   primitive type; any primitive wrapper
>   type; `java.lang.String`;
>   `java.util.Date`; `java.sql.Date`**. In
>   general, however, approximate numeric
>   types (e.g., floating point types)
>   should never be used in primary keys.
>   Entities whose primary keys use types
>   other than these will not be portable.
>   If generated primary keys are used,
>   only integral types will be portable.
>   If `java.util.Date` is used as a
>   primary key field or property, the
>   temporal type should be specified as
>   `DATE`.

What are they exactly (enumerations?)?

Apart from that, the approach to map a composite key itself is OK (see related question below).

#### Related questions

- [How to map a composite key with Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585034/how-to-map-a-composite-key-with-hibernate/3588400#3588400)

Comment: Yes - they are enumerations.  I hadn't realised they couldn't be used, thanks for the info.  How else could I achieve this behaviour??

Comment: @Lainie I'm afraid you'd have to map them as string to obtain this exact behavior (maybe performing some conversion into enums in getters/setters). But honestly, it's kinda weird to use a limited set of values (NxM) for the key of a table which is typically unlimited. If you can change your database design, my suggestion would be to use a real `Id`.

Comment: I know - it was weird design, which reflected a specific and fixed dataset.  Went with the real Id solution - thanks for your help!