# Hibernate second id

Tags: spring, hibernate, primary-key

is it possible to define two keys in hibernate, so i can hit the first-level-cache with both keys?

```
@Entity
class User {
  @Id
  int id;

  @Id
  String username;
}
```

so session.get(User.class, 'harry') is the same as session.get(User.class, 1)

is it possible?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3588400/1085285

Comment: @Fidrizers the op asks for 2 ids which are unique on their own not together which rules out compositeId

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interested in [this](http://relation.to/22795.lace) feature of 4.1

You can in fact hit the first level cache using the @Id or the @NaturalId. Just make sure you are using 4.1.x.

Comment: hi thanks thats the same as in Firo's link, works great, fortunately i had already upgraded my hibernate version

Comment: They're very different links. @firos link is referring to a blog post in 2009 and talks about simply not checking the second level cache for expiration - this will not hit the session cache. The link I've posted refers to new functionality which will hit the session cache when you use the natural id.

Comment: hm i tried the example of Firo, but when querying for the natural id with criteria hibernate recommends to use "session.byNaturalId" so i used this. are there any other differences?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Using session.byNaturalId will ensure that you hit the first level cache. Is that not what you wanted? Using a Query will never hit the first level cache.

Comment: hi, yes everything is fine now, thats exactly what i wanted. i just wanted to tell you that i already came to the soulution with "session.byNaturalId" because of hibernate's log message when querying for it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

short answer: **no**

long answer: there is the @NaturalId annotation which does a little, [**see here**](http://ayende.com/blog/4061/nhibernate-natural-id),  but there is only ever one id for hibernate. you could implement your own using a dictionary.