# How to mapping composite primary key in many to one realtion using hiberante

Tags: mysql, hibernate

Iam working ManyToOne mapping In that how to call the composite primary key in reference column on mapping how to do this please suggested me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585034/how-to-map-a-composite-key-with-hibernate) it is already answered. Please go through this , if you have any other query then let us know.

You ca also find well explained answer [here](http://www.java4s.com/hibernate/example-on-composite-primary-key-in-hibernate/).

Comment: Hi,iam asking how to working on composite primary key in ManyToOne annotation please suggested me