# Hibernate update entity not knowing primary key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-criteria

I have a US entity which has a id that is primary key and a userId and a ServiceId that these last two together they too are unique. now I have a userId and a serviceId and I wanna update a US entity and I don't know the correct syntax using hibernate to do that. Would any one help me, please...
I've used annotation for entity mapping:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "USERSERVICE_ID")
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "SERVICE_ID")
private Service service;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "SERVICE_SEND_TYPE_ID")
private ServiceSendType serviceSendType;

@Column(name = "USERSERVICE_LASTSENT")
private String lastSentValue = "";

@Column(name = "USERSERVICE_UNSUBCTIMESTAMP")
private Date unsubscribeDate;

@Column(name = "USERSERVICE_SUBCTIMESTAMP")
private Date subscribeDate;

@Column(name = "USERSERVICE_ENABLED")
private Boolean enabled = false;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "SERVICE_USER_ID")
private User user;
```

Comment: Can you provide the code of the class you want to map?

Comment: Alright, but I've already mapped the entity and it's working correctly with other hibernate functions. I just wanna use this two value (userId, serviceId) instead of the primary key (id) to update an entity

Comment: You sholud use composite primary key. Read here about it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585034/how-to-map-a-composite-key-with-hibernate"

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
US entity = (US) session.createQuery("select s from US u where u.service.id = :serviceId and u.user.id = :userId")
.setParameter("serviceId", serviceId)
.setParameter("userId", userId)
.uniqueResult();
//update
entity.setEnabled(true);
```

That's it. Once the entity is loaded from DB, it's automatically attached to the current Session, so any change will be detected by the [automatic dirty checking mechanism](http://vladmihalcea.com/the-anatomy-of-hibernate-dirty-checking/).