# Using Hibernate Get with Multi-Column Primary Key

Tags: java, hibernate, primary-key, composite-primary-key

Say I have a class that looks like this:

```
public class MyClass {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "ID")
  private long Id;
}
```

I can use a hibernate session to do a get or load on the class like this:

```
MyClass a = (MyClass)session.get(MyClass.class, new Long(100));
```

However, assume I have a class with multiple columns as the primary key:

```
public MyJoinClass implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -5L;
  @Id
  @Column(name = "ID")
  private long id;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "EMAIL_ADDRESS_ID")
  private long emailAddressId;
}
```

Is it possible to use get or load with such a class?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to use and `@IdClass` or `@EmbeddedId`

```
public MyJoinClass implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -5L;

  @EmbeddedId
  private MyJoinClassKey key;
}

public MyJoinClassKey implements Serializable{

  @Column(name = "ID")
  private long id;

  @Column(name = "EMAIL_ADDRESS_ID")
  private long emailAddressId;
}
```

Then use

```
MyJoinClass a = (MyJoinClass )session.get(MyJoinClass .class, new MyJoinClassKey (1, "email"));
```

Take a look at this question, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585034/how-to-map-a-composite-key-with-hibernate) is broadly explained. Basically hibernate have a mechanism for compound keys.

Comment: Hi @Koitoer, Suppose there are several rows with the same id. How do we query them using session.get without providing emailAddressId. It means I want all the entries with the same Id using session.get.

Comment: to be honest I am not sure if that will be possible as you already defined a composed key in the jpa model, you could  obviously use HQL to do that but that will create createQuery for session

Comment: Hibernate [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-composite) says "_Hibernate does allow composite identifiers to be defined without a "primary key class" via multiple @Id attributes._". Is there a way to get the entity without any `@EmbeddedId`?

Comment: I'm sure your solution works, but at this point I prefer to do a normal query. More simple.

Answer (score 1):

In Hibernate yes ([documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-composite-associations)):

```java
MyJoinClass a = session.get(MyJoinClass.class, new MyJoinClass(100, 200));
```

Just make sure to have a constructor with all parts of the composite key (and don't forgot the default public constructor with no parameters):

```java
public MyJoinClass implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -5L;
  @Id
  @Column(name = "ID")
  private long id;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "EMAIL_ADDRESS_ID")
  private long emailAddressId;

  public MyJoinClass() {}

  public MyJoinClass(long id, long emailAddressId) {
    this.id= id;
    this.emailAddressId= emailAddressId;
  }
}
```