# Hibernate entity without PK but has FK

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa

I am getting exception : `org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity`

I know that hibernate must have @Id in an entity class but in my table there are no primary keys just two foreign keys. How do i map the hibernate entity class without errors?

For example the class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="building_block")
public class BuildingBlock implements Serializable {

    private Integer archId;
    private Integer mirrorId; //foreign key to Mirror table
    private Integer makeId; //foreign key to Maker table
    private Integer sweepId;
    private String search;
    private Integer length;
    private Date createDate;

    @Column(name="arch_id")
    public Integer getArchId() {
        return ArchId;
    }
    public void setArchId(Integer ArchId) {
        this.ArchId = ArchId;
    }
    @Column(name="mirror_id")
    public Integer getMirrorId() {
        return mirrorId;
    }
    public void setMirrorId(Integer mirrorId) {
        this.mirrorId = mirrorId;
    }
    @Column(name="make_id")
    public Integer getMakeId() {
        return makeId;
    }
    public void setMakeId(Integer makeId) {
        this.makeId = makeId;
    }

    ...

    @Column(name="create_date")
    public Date getCreateDate() {
        return createDate;
    }
    public void setCreateDate(Date createDate) {
        this.createDate = createDate;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the corresponding SQL table look like? That is, which columns make up the table's primary key (either declared or implied)?

Comment: Although it is totally possible to add composite PKs in Hibernate (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13936340/how-to-create-hibernate-composite-key-using-annotations), I would discourage it, unless you're working on a legacy DB on which you can't perform any schema change.

Answer (score 0):

You must add primary key column and  declare a primary key in the entity.

Ref : http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id

> Mapped classes must declare the primary key column of the database
>   table

Comment: I know i must declare a primary key but is there work around? in my case

Comment: Hope this will help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/925818/hibernate-persistence-without-id

Answer (score 0):

You could try to make those foreign keys the primary keys of your entity by making a composite id.

To see how to make composite keys follow this link ([How to map a composite key with Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585034/how-to-map-a-composite-key-with-hibernate))

Answer (score 0):

If you know that a set of fields can always identify a specific record, you can group them together and tell Hibernate to use that as the primary key.

See [Using Hibernate Get with Multi-Column Primary Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29925784/using-hibernate-get-with-multi-column-primary-key) for how to do this.