# Hibernate Multiple id properties Not Working properly

Tags: java, hibernate, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have an entity with composite id , I'm using hibernate's Multiple id properties without identifier type , like so :

```
@Entity
class MyEntity  implements Serializable {

   @Id
   private Long id1;

   @Id
   private Long id2;

   //... Getters , setters , hashcode , equals ...
}
```

The problem is that in my Database: id1 = 1  ,  id2 = 2

And if I want to add a row with : id1 = 2 , id2 = 2

I get an error ConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '2' for key 'id2'

I'm using hibernate 4.1.7,
The documentation link : http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#mapping-declaration-id

## Update

I'm talking about a Hibernate-specific solution: Map multiple properties as @Id properties without declaring an external class to be the identifier type

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585034/how-to-map-a-composite-key-with-hibernate

Comment: Thanks, but I just want to know why it's not working

Comment: It's impossible to know that with that small code sample.

Answer (score 0):

Use EmbeddedId. Please refer [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/EmbeddedId.html).

Comment: Thanks , I know that it work with EmbeddedId. But in Hibernate docs there is a section '5.1.2.1.2.Multiple id properties without identifier type' , where they say that it work without EmbeddedId , and you can check the code snippet they give

Answer (score 0):

It's very possible the problem is not your code, but your db schema.  Without knowing what DBMS you're using and the constraints/indexes on the table for `MyEntity`, it's impossible to say for sure.  However my guess is that you have something like this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON my_entity (id1);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON my_entity (id2);
```

which requires that each column independently contains only unique values, when you really want something like this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON my_entity (id1, id2);
```

which allows each column to contain duplicates of the same value, as long as the combination of both columns is unique.