# Missing column listing wrong column name

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql

Details below but the short version is: I have a column `user_id` on a PostgreSQL table called `config`. That column is referenced using `@Column(name = "user_id")` but when my server starts, the `EntityManagerFactory` can't be built because:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing column: userId in public.config
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Table.validateColumns(Table.java:366)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validateSchema(Configuration.java:1305)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:512)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1797)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914)
    ... 31 more
```

So it seems like I'm missing something here that is causing Hibernate to look for a `userId` column instead of a column called `user_id`.

Details:

The table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE config
(
  user_id character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  application_id integer NOT NULL,
  step_id integer NOT NULL,
  prompt_id integer NOT NULL,
  default_value character varying(255),
  CONSTRAINT "PK_Config" PRIMARY KEY (user_id, application_id, step_id, prompt_id),
  CONSTRAINT "FK_Config_User" FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
      REFERENCES app_user (user_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE config
  OWNER TO appuser;
```

The Hibernate entity is defined as:

```
// ...

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.IdClass;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "config")
@IdClass(ConfigId.class)
public class Config {

    private String userId;
    private Integer applicationId;
    private Integer stepId;
    private Integer promptId;
    private String defaultValue;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "application_id")
    public Integer getApplicationId() {
        return applicationId;
    }

    public void setApplicationId(Integer applicationId) {
        this.applicationId = applicationId;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "step_id")
    public Integer getStepId() {
        return stepId;
    }

    public void setStepId(Integer stepId) {
        this.stepId = stepId;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "prompt_id")
    public Integer getPromptId() {
        return promptId;
    }

    public void setPromptId(Integer promptId) {
        this.promptId = promptId;
    }

    @Column(name = "default_value", columnDefinition = "nvarchar")
    public String getDefaultValue() {
        return defaultValue;
    }

    public void setDefaultValue(String defaultValue) {
        this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
    }

}
```

Where ConfigId is defined as:

```
// ...

public class ConfigId implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5372509566187824168L;

    private String userId;
    private Integer applicationId;
    private Integer stepId;
    private Integer promptId;

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public Integer getApplicationId() {
        return applicationId;
    }

    public void setApplicationId(Integer applicationId) {
        this.applicationId = applicationId;
    }

    public Integer getStepId() {
        return stepId;
    }

    public void setStepId(Integer stepId) {
        this.stepId = stepId;
    }

    public Integer getPromptId() {
        return promptId;
    }

    public void setPromptId(Integer promptId) {
        this.promptId = promptId;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
       // ...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
       // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like you are right. All I can suggest you is to move your annotations to fields. It works for me

Comment: @InsFi, thanks for the suggestion. I moved the annotations to fields and it is still complaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crap. I had another entity that referenced my Config entity with `@JoinColumn(name = "userId")`. I was able to fix that and everything works now. I really wish the error message had been more clear as to where "userId" was coming from.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing composite-key in your code. This example has been explained brilliantly: [Composite-Key and Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585034/how-to-map-a-composite-key-with-hibernate/3588400#3588400)

Comment: I read through that answer and it looks like I've done all of that using the `@IdClass` annotation. Did you see something specific that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same problem. My issue seemed to be a mix usage of where the @column annotations were defined.

In my entity class, @column annotations where defined at the getter method. When creating my @Embeddable class for my composite id, the @column annotations were defined at the field level. I made sure all my @Column annotations were at my getter methods and all started working.