# How to convert this UML to JPA entities

Tags: java, jpa

I have this UML diagram.

[image]

And I tried to build entities like this (I renamed `Entity` class to `Entidad`)

RelationshipType.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "relationship_type")
public class RelationshipType {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String type;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "relationshipType", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Relationship> relationships = new HashSet<Relationship>();
    //Getters and Setters
```

Relationship.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "relationship")
public class Relationship {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    private RelationshipType relationshipType;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    private Entidad entity;
    //Getters and Setters
```

Entidad.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity")
public class Entidad {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String image;

    private String foundationNotes;

    private String alias;

    private Boolean excludeNotifications;

    private String notes;

    //[...]

    @ManyToOne 
    private Relationship related;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entity", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Relationship> relationships = new HashSet<Relationship>();
```

But when I launch app throws this:

```
Foreign key (FK_9d8afoh1pv9r59iwjkbcpnud1:entity [])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (relationship [relationshipType_id,entity_id])
```

At now, I don't know where is the problem and need do this well because I'm using this entities to build the DB schema.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585034/how-to-map-a-composite-key-with-hibernate

Comment: I think I'ts a different case, in this question I have 2 calls from Relationship in the same entity

Comment: can you comment out these lines one by one and confirm if the error is because of Many to One  :  @ManyToOne 
         private Relationship related;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entity", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        private Set<Relationship> relationships = new     HashSet<Relationship>();

Comment: @amitmahajan yes, if I comment `@ManyToOne private Relationship related;` and implements Serializable in RelationshipType it works, but I think i need this field, but I'm not sure (I never use a UML diagram...)

Comment: I am not using hibernate anymore for long time now. As i understand the problem is because hibernate is not able to relate entity to relationship. You may need to specify a column attribute on the ManyToOne annotation.

Comment: When you want to use multiple columns for the primary key you need a composite key in hibernate. Unless you do it so, the foreign key from the relation table couldn't reference multi-column primary key of the relationship type.