# Hibernate foreign key with a part of composite primary key

Tags: java, hibernate, foreign-keys, composite-key, composite-primary-key

I have to work with Hibernate and I am not very sure how to solve this problem, I have 2 tables with a 1..n relationship like this:

```
-------
TABLE_A
-------
col_b (pk)
col_c (pk)
[other fields]

-------
TABLE_B
-------
col_a (pk)
col_b (pk) (fk TABLE_A.col_b)
col_c (fk TABLE_A.col_c)
[other fields]
```

How can I manage this with Hibernate?

I do not have any idea how to declare a foreign key that would contain a part of primary key.

My database schema is generated from the Hibernate model.

Comment: If you want to fight hibernate... go ahead and use composite keys. If you want a much easier life, ensure each table has a single primary key column. Trust me, it's not worth the fight... it's a battle which will cost you many hours in the future

Comment: What do you mean by "part of primary key"? Composite primary keys in Hibernate are quite simple, but you shouldn't try to complicate that by trying to use only a part of it.

Basicly you need a composite key class. There is an answer here with all basic details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585034/how-to-map-a-composite-key-with-hibernate

Comment: There's a fairly thorough answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3588400/3166303

Comment: For one-to-many mappings you don't require a composite key. It is so so easier to manage this situation without using composite key.

Comment: @LanceJava In this case I need to use composite keys because of readability.

Comment: @leeor This answer does not help at all in my case. It is only about how to define a composite key.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47890019/hibernate-model Could you please suggest on this query.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have found two solutions to this problem.

The first one is rather a workaround and is not so neat as the second one.

Define the primary key of the `B` entity as composite key containing `col_a`, `col_b`, and `col_c` and what was supposed to be the primary key in the first place, define as unique constraint. The disadvantage is that the column `col_c` is not really conceptually a part of primary key.

```
@Entity
class A {
  @Id
  private int b;
  @Id
  private int c;
}

@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "a", "b" }) })
class B {
  @Id
  private int a;

  @Id
  @ManyToOne(optional = false)
  @JoinColumns(value = {
          @JoinColumn(name = "b", referencedColumnName = "b"),
          @JoinColumn(name = "c", referencedColumnName = "c") })
  private A entityA;
}
```

The second uses `@EmbeddedId` and `@MapsId` annotations and does exactly what I wanted to be done at the very beginning.

```
@Entity
class A {
  @Id
  private int b;
  @Id
  private int c;
}

@Embeddable
class BKey {
  private int a;
  private int b;
}

@Entity
class B {
  @EmbeddedId
  private BKey primaryKey;

  @MapsId("b")
  @ManyToOne(optional = false)
  @JoinColumns(value = {
          @JoinColumn(name = "b", referencedColumnName = "b"),
          @JoinColumn(name = "c", referencedColumnName = "c") })
  private A entityA;
}
```

Comment: To get above code work you also need to implement Serializable for all above classes

Comment: I tried this way and I'm getting `Unable to find column reference in the @MapsId mapping: c`. Any idea?. TIA

Comment: Is it a runtime or compile error? Could you post your code somewhere so that I can have a look at it?

Comment: Is it possible to have MapsId for two attrributes? For example, if there was an attribute 'd' which is also part of both keys (same as b)?

Comment: @schoenk Maybe try with another `@MapsId("d")` annotation, so that you will have two annotations in the end: `@MapsId("b")` and `@MapsId("d")`.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible to have multiple ´@MapsId´ annotations on the same attribute. But I managed to solve it for my use case by using ´@JoinFormula´ instead of ´@JoinColumn´ for the columns that are used in Primary Key as well as Foreign Key.

Answer (score -1):

Jagger's second solution that is my first reaction, with @EmbededId and @MapsId. The following is another way based on his second solution but without using @MapsId. 
`

```
@Entity
class A {
  @Id
  private int b;
  @Id
  private int c;
}

@Embeddable
class BKey {
  private int a;
  private int b;
}

@Entity
class B {
  @EmbeddedId
  private BKey primaryKey;

  @ManyToOne(optional = false)
  @JoinColumns(value = {
          @JoinColumn(name = "b", referencedColumnName = "b", insertable= false, updatable= false),
          @JoinColumn(name = "c", referencedColumnName = "c") }, )
  private A entityA;
}
```

Comment: This won't work and ends with an exception `org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Mixing insertable and non insertable columns in a property is not allowed` There is a Hibernate [bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6221) for it .