# Hibernate model

Tags: java, hibernate

I have to work with Hibernate and I am not very sure how to solve this problem, I have 2 tables with a 1..n relationship like this:

```
-------
TABLE_A
-------
col_A1 (pk)
col_A2 (pk)
[other fields]

-------
TABLE_B
-------
col_B1 (pk) (fk TABLE_A.col_A1)
col_B2 (pk) 
col_B3      (fk TABLE_A.col_A2)
[other fields]
```

How can I manage this with Hibernate?

I do not have any idea how to declare a foreign key that would contain a part of primary key.

My database schema is generated from the Hibernate model.

Comment: share your hibernate model class

Comment: how is it possible for TABLE_A  and TABLE_B to have 2 (PK)

Comment: @FarazPV `composite primary key`

Comment: [this might be good source of information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32625410/hibernate-foreign-key-with-a-part-of-composite-primary-key?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: table structure is like

Comment: -------
TABLE_A
-------
col_id (pk)
col_key (pk)
[other fields]

-------
TABLE_B
-------
col_id (pk) (fk TABLE_A.col_id)
col_key (pk) 
col_parentkey      (fk TABLE_A.col_key)
[other fields]

TABLE_A is one to many relation with TABLE_B.

TABLE_A.id and TABLE_A.key are primary key (composite key).
TABLE_B.id and TABLE_B.key are primary key (composite key).
At the same time TABLE_B.parentkey is same as TABLE_A.key and TABLE_B.id is same as TABLE_A.id

Comment: It has not been possible in Hibernate for years. There is an open bug for that that has not been assigned for ages. https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6221