# how to create table with 2 primary key fields hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jersey

i'm trying to create tabel entity with composite primary key.
so i  tried to create `@Embeddable` class with all the primary keys and use `@EmbeddedId` on the field that represents the  primary keys. but i get this error:

`Caused by: org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.`

i wos tried to follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585034/how-to-map-a-composite-key-with-hibernate/3588400#3588400) bat noting work 
what i'm doing wrong?

here is my code

**DocEntity**

```
@Entity(name = "doc")
@Table(name = "doc")
public class DocEntity extends baseDataBase implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    @EmbeddedId
    private DocID docID;

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "DocID")
    @JsonProperty
    @NotEmpty
    private short id;

    @Column(name = "DocDescription")
    @JsonProperty
    @NotEmpty
    private String docDescription;

    @Column(name = "DocPath")
    @JsonProperty
    @NotEmpty
    private String docPath;

     // getters, setters ,equals, hashCode
}
```

**DocID**

```
@Embeddable
public class DocID implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "DocName")
    @JsonProperty
    @NotEmpty
    protected  String docName;


    @Column(name = "DocVersion")
    @JsonProperty
    @NotEmpty
    protected  String docVersion;

 // getters, setters ,equals, hashCode
}
```

what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: If you mean *two* primary keys, then you are missing the meaning of "primary".  There is only one per table.  You should clarify if you mean *composite primary key* or *two* different primary keys.

Comment: Sorry I thought it was clear that it refers for a composite primary key i will edit the post