# How to map multiple composite keys in Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, composite-primary-key

I have a table with 3 primary keys. They are `custom_id`, `patient_idpatient`, `service_provider_type_idservice_provider_type`. My current mapping is like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="beans.ServiceProvider" table="service_provider" catalog="myglukose" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="customId" type="string">
            <column name="custom_id" not-null="true"/>
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="patient" class="beans.Patient" fetch="select">
            <column name="patient_idpatient" not-null="true"/>
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="serviceProviderType" class="beans.ServiceProviderType" fetch="select">
            <column name="service_provider_type_idservice_provider_type" not-null="true"/>
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="dateCreated" type="timestamp">
            <column name="date_created" length="19" />
        </property>
        <property name="lastUpdated" type="timestamp">
            <column name="last_updated" length="19" not-null="true" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

my SQL code

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `xxx`.`service_provider` (
  `custom_id` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `patient_idpatient` INT NOT NULL,
  `service_provider_type_idservice_provider_type` INT NOT NULL,
  `date_created` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  `last_updated` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  INDEX `fk_service_provider_patient1_idx` (`patient_idpatient` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_service_provider_service_provider_type1_idx` (`service_provider_type_idservice_provider_type` ASC),
  PRIMARY KEY (`custom_id`, `patient_idpatient`, `service_provider_type_idservice_provider_type`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_service_provider_patient1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`patient_idpatient`)
    REFERENCES `xxx`.`patient` (`idpatient`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_service_provider_service_provider_type1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`service_provider_type_idservice_provider_type`)
    REFERENCES `xxx`.`service_provider_type` (`idservice_provider_type`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

How can I map these 3 composite keys?

Comment: Do you really mean multiple primary keys? Or do you mean Composite Primary Key? I don't think multiple pkeys are possible....

Comment: `patient_idpatient` and `service_provider_type_idservice_provider_type` aren't primary keys of service_provider, they're *foreign keys* in that table, because they're primary keys of other tables

Comment: @Ben: OK, so I was creating this via `mysql work bench`. Yeah I think you are correct, please check the update.

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for a composite key, not multiple PKeys.

This can look like this in Hibernate (via hbm.xml):

```
<composite-id name="compId">
   <key-property name="customId” column="custom_id" />
   <key-property name="patientIdpatient" column="patient_idpatient" />
   <key-property name="serviceProviderTypeIdserviceProviderType" column="service_provider_type_idservice_provider_type" />
</composite-id>
```

or with Annotation like Style:

search for `@EmbeddedId`

You can read about more details e.g here (simmilar question):
[How to map a composite key with Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585034/how-to-map-a-composite-key-with-hibernate)

**EDIT**
Here is a simple code example, which (maybe) can help you to show the correct direction:

Your hbm.xml can look like (**not tested, code may not work without corrections!**):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="beans.ServiceProvider" table="service_provider" catalog="myglukose" optimistic-lock="version">

        <composite-id name="myId">
            <key-property name="customId” column="custom_id" />
            <key-property name="patientIdpatient" column="patient_idpatient" />
            <key-property name="serviceProviderTypeIdserviceProviderType" column="service_provider_type_idservice_provider_type" />
        </composite-id>

        <!-- not sure with this part...maybe not needed -->
        <many-to-one name="patient" class="beans.Patient" fetch="select">
            <column name="patient_idpatient" not-null="true"/>
        </many-to-one>

        <!-- not sure with this part...maybe not needed -->
        <many-to-one name="serviceProviderType" class="beans.ServiceProviderType" fetch="select">
            <column name="service_provider_type_idservice_provider_type" not-null="true"/>
        </many-to-one>

        <property name="dateCreated" type="timestamp">
            <column name="date_created" length="19" />
        </property>

        <property name="lastUpdated" type="timestamp">
            <column name="last_updated" length="19" not-null="true" />
        </property>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and this could be the Id-Class: (**not tested!**):

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class MyId implements Serializable {
  private beans.ServiceProviderType spt;
  private int customId;
  private beans.Patient pat;

  // an easy initializing constructor
  public MyId(int customId, beans.Patient pat, beans.ServiceProviderType spt) {
    this.pat = pat;
    this.customId = customId;
    this.spt = spt;
  }

  public beans.Patient getPatient() {
    return pat;
  }

  public void setPatient(beans.Patient pat) {
     this.pat = pat;
  }

  public beans.ServiceProviderType getServiceProviderType() {
    return spt;
  }

  public void setServiceProviderType(beans.ServiceProviderType pat) {
     this.spt = spt;
  }

  public int getCustomId() {
     return customerId;
  }

  public void setCustomId(int customId) {
    this.customId = customId;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object arg0) {
    //needs implementation
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    //needs implementation
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please edit it by adding the code into my given mapping code? I can't find whether I should delete the relationship mapping which I have done, whether I should remove the primary key mapping I have done and so on before adding your code.

Comment: @PeakGen see my Edit. You just have to try a little (and read the docs), it's pretty easy...