# Using @IdClass with Hibernate and arquillian force CascadeType.Insert on a ManyToOne foreign key object that is part of entity composite primary key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I am trying to persist a new Order object from my arquillian test class.
The order entity contains a list of OrderDetail entity which has a composed primary key of 4 fields.

But while Hibernate is trying to insert the new OrderDetail object it also insert the **NOT NEW** Item object (Item is one of the main PK fields in the OrderDetail entity and annotated with @ID )  , and this results in a unique constrain exception from the Item table in the DB.

Note that I removed the CascadeType from the Item @OneToMany annotation
and tried also the CascadeType.Refresh but I got the same result and nothing changed. It works as it force CascadeType.Insert in all cases.

It **worked** as expected when I used **@EmbeddedId** annotation instead of **@IDClass**
But I want to know why it did not work with @IDClass ? is it a bug in Hibernate ? It should work perfectly as per the [JPA 2.1 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf?AuthParam=1495460756_914304172b47491768c9fb17cd7a3742).

**Order Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ORDERS")
public class Orders extends BaseEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ORDERNO")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long orderNo ;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "order", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<OrderDetail> orderDetailsList ;

    // setters and getters
}
```

**OrderDetail Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ORDERDETAILS")
@IdClass(OrderDetailsPK.class)
public class OrderDetail extends BaseEntity {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@JoinColumn(name = "ORDERNO", referencedColumnName = "ORDERNO")
@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Orders order;

@Id
@JoinColumn( name = "ITEMNO", referencedColumnName = "ITEMNO", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH,optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
//@Cascade({CascadeType.DETACH}) // I tried this but did not work, it keep try to insert the item.
private Item item;

@Id
@Column(name = "LINETYPE")
private String lineType;

@Id
@Column(name = "PROMITEMNO")
private String promItemNo;
```

**Item Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ITEM")
public class Item extends BaseEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ITEMNO")
    private String itemno;
    // setters and getters

   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (itemno != null ? itemno.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object object) {
    if (!(object instanceof Item)) {
        return false;
    }
    Item other = (Item) object;
    System.out.println("Item Equal Method = " + !((this.itemno == null &&        other.itemno != null) || (this.itemno != null && !this.itemno.equals(other.itemno))));
    return !((this.itemno == null && other.itemno != null) || (this.itemno != null && !this.itemno.equals(other.itemno)));
}

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "com.unilever.sas.model.entities.masterdata.Item[ itemno=" + itemno + " ]";
}

}
```

**OrderDetailsPK**

```
public class OrderDetailsPK  implements Serializable 
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long order;
    private String item;
    private String lineType;
    private String promItemNo;

    public OrderDetailsPK() {
    }

    public OrderDetailsPK(Long order, String item, String lineType, String promItemNo) {
        this.order = order;
        this.item = item;
        this.lineType = lineType;
        this.promItemNo = promItemNo;
    }

    public Long getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    public String getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public String getLineType() {
        return lineType;
    }


    public String getPromItemNo() {
        return promItemNo;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 5;
        hash = 73 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.order);
        hash = 73 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.item);
        hash = 73 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.lineType);
        hash = 73 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.promItemNo);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final OrderDetailsPK other = (OrderDetailsPK) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.item, other.item)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.lineType, other.lineType)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.promItemNo, other.promItemNo)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.order, other.order)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "OrderDetailsPK{" + "order=" + order + ", item=" + item + ", lineType=" + lineType + ", promItemNo=" + promItemNo + '}';
    }
```

**Arquillian Test**

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class OrdersFacadeTest
{


@Inject
OrdersFacadeLocal ordersFacade ;

@Inject    
ItemFacadeLocal itemFacade ;

@Test
public void testCreateOrder() throws Exception 
{
    Item item = itemFacade.find("20247912");
    Orders order = new Orders();

    OrderDetail orderDetail = new OrderDetail();
    orderDetail.setOrder(order);
    orderDetail.setItem(item);
    orderDetail.setLineType("NLI");
    orderDetail.setPromItemNo("99999");

    List<OrderDetail> orderDeialsList = new ArrayList<>();
    orderDeialsList.add(orderDetail);

    order.setOrderDetailsList(orderDeialsList);      

    ordersFacade.create(order);

    Orders createdOrder = ordersFacade.find(order.getOrderNo());
    assertEquals(order, createdOrder);
}
```

Comment: suppose this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585034/how-to-map-a-composite-key-with-hibernate/) may be helpful to get a understanding on how it works.

Comment: If you can replicate it with a [test case](http://in.relation.to/2016/01/14/hibernate-jpa-test-case-template/), then you should open a Jira issue.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a bug, but there are also some strange mapping choices here as well.

Why does the `@JoinColumn` is not allowed to set the FK on insert or update? Who should set the FK in this case?

```
@JoinColumn( 
    name = "ITEMNO", 
    referencedColumnName = "ITEMNO", 
    insertable = false, updatable = false
)
```

If you can replicate it with a [test case](http://in.relation.to/2016/01/14/hibernate-jpa-test-case-template/), then you should open a Jira issue.

Comment: This is because this FK is part of the composite PK and annotated with @ID

Comment: Also I found something else very strange, when I moved the test function logic to the OrderFacade EJB and just call this function from the my arquillian test class it works normally !!!