Link Two Collections Using @DBRef or @DocumentReference. Store logged in user`s id in Expense as ref within the controller
I am working on Rest API project (Called Expense Tracker) with Spring boot and MongoDB. I have User and Expense tables. A user can have many expenses, and I want to model this relation. I want to add the current user's id to Expense as reference automatically each time the user created a new expense. For example, Jack is logged in now so, I add his id as reference when creates a new expense. Then, Mark is logged in and I want to do the same. I want this because I want each user to only view his expenses and not other people`s
User Class
@Document(collection = "users")
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    public String id;
    @NotBlank(message = "First Name field required")
    public String firstName;
    @NotBlank(message = "Last Name field required")
    public String lastName;
    @NotBlank(message = "Email field required")
    public String email;
    @NotBlank(message = "password field required")
    public String password;

    @DBRef
    public List<Expense> expenses;

    public List<Expense> getExpenses() {
        return expenses;
    }

    public void setExpenses(List<Expense> expenses) {
        this.expenses = expenses;
    } 
       /* rest of methods */

Expense class
public class Expense {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @NotBlank(message = "item field required")
    private String item;

    @NotBlank(message = "shop field required")
    private String shop;

    @Min(value = 1L, message = "Minimum is £1")
    private int price;

    @NotBlank(message = "Category field required")
    private String category;

    @NotNull(message = "Date field required")
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private LocalDate date;

    @NotNull(message = "Time field required")
    // @JsonProperty
    private LocalTime time;

I added @DBRef to User class and hoped it would work because I though it would automatically add it. I checked the database and there is no reference. When I add a new expense, it returns the id of the newly created expense. In the controller, I tried adding it but user` id is string and expenses is type of List
@PostMapping()
    public ResponseEntity<Expense> addExpense(@RequestBody @Valid Expense expense) {


        LocalTime time = expense.getTime();
        LocalTime truncatedTime = time.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
        expense.setTime(truncatedTime);
         
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        User currentUser = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();

        expenseService.saveExpense(expense);
        return new ResponseEntity<Expense>(expense, HttpStatus.CREATED);

    }


Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52004135/spring-boot-jpa-how-to-implement-foreign-key-between-users-and-authorities-table

Not really. I am using MongoDB with Spring Boot but this one uses Spring JPA.
