# Hibernate Constraint Primary Key

Tags: java, hibernate

```
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
@Entity
@Table(name = "AHMGAVMS_MSTDECLARS")
public class AhmgavmsDecs extends DefaultEntityImpl implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "VDECTYPE")
    private String vdectype;
    
    @Column(name = "VPLANTID")
    private String vplantid;

    @Column(name = "VTITLE")
    private String vtitle;
    
    @Column(name = "VBODYID")
    private String vbodyid;
    
    @Column(name = "VBODYEN")
    private String vbodyen;
    
    @Column(name = "DSTARTEFF")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dstarteff;
    
    @Column(name = "DENDEFF")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dendeff;
    
    @Column(name = "VVERSION")
    private int vversion;

    @Column(name = "VSEQ")
    private String vseq;
    
    @Column(name = "VFTYPEDOC")
    private String vftypedoc;
    
    @Column(name = "VFNAMEDOC")
    private String vfnamedoc;
    
    @Column(name = "VFEXTDOC")
    private String vfextdoc;
    
    @Column(name = "VFPATHDOC")
    private String vfpathdoc;
    
    @Column(name = "VFTYPEFOTO")
    private String vftypefoto;
    
    @Column(name = "VFNAMEFOTO")
    private String vfnamefoto;
    
    @Column(name = "VFEXTFOTO")
    private String vfextfoto;
    
    @Column(name = "VFPATHFOTO")
    private String vfpathfoto;

    @Column(name = "VSTATUS")
    private String vstatus;
}
```

i have 1 entity to maintain some document, but in database i have 1 primary key and 1 constraint primary key (VDECTYPE AND VPLANTID). when i insert data im using VDECTYPE for primary key. The plan, i need make 2 rows with same primary key(VDECTYPE) but different value every rows. when i try insert, i got primary key violated constaint. can anyone help me about this problem. Thanks

```
AhmgavmsDecs dec = new AhmgavmsDecs();
            dec = vms032AhmgavmsDecsDao.findOne(declarationType);
            int count = vms032AhmgavmsDecsDao.getVersionData(input);
            if(dec == null ){
                    AhmgavmsDecs decs = new AhmgavmsDecs();
                    decs.setVdectype(declarationType);
                    decs.setVplantid("ALL");
                    decs.setVtitle(declarationType);
                    decs.setVstatus("Y");
                    decs.setDstarteff(dateStart);
                    decs.setDendeff(dateEnd);
                    decs.setVbodyid(escapeHtmlIndonesia);
                    decs.setVbodyen(escapeHtmlInggris);
                    decs.setVversion(count+1);
                    decs.setVseq(sequence);
                    decs.setCreateDate(new Date());
                    decs.setCreateBy(userId);
                    decs.setLastModDate(new Date());
                    decs.setLastModBy(userId);
                    
//                    uploadToServer();
                    
                    vms032AhmgavmsDecsDao.save(decs);
                    vms032AhmgavmsDecsDao.flush();
                    return DtoHelper.constructResponseWorkspace(StatusMsgEnum.SUKSES, null, null);
           }else{
                    
                    if(status.equals("N")){
                        AhmgavmsHisDeclrs his = new AhmgavmsHisDeclrs();
                        his.setVdecstype(declarationType);
                        his.setVplantid("ALL");
                        his.setVtitle(declarationType);
                        his.setVbodyid(escapeHtmlIndonesia);
                        his.setVbodyen(escapeHtmlInggris);
                        his.setDstarteff(dateStart);
                        his.setDendeff(dateEnd);
                        his.setVseq(sequence);
                        his.setVversion(count);
                        his.setCreateDate(new Date());
                        his.setCreateBy(userId);
                        his.setLastModDate(new Date());
                        his.setLastModBy(userId);
                        
                        vms032AhmgavmsHisDeclrsDao.save(his);
                        vms032AhmgavmsHisDeclrsDao.flush();
                        return DtoHelper.constructResponseWorkspace(StatusMsgEnum.SUKSES, null, null);
                    }else{
                    dec.setVstatus("Y");
                    dec.setDstarteff(dateStart);
                    dec.setDendeff(dateEnd);
                    dec.setVbodyid(escapeHtmlIndonesia);
                    dec.setVbodyen(escapeHtmlInggris);
                    dec.setVseq(sequence);
                    dec.setVversion(count+1);
                    dec.setCreateDate(new Date());
                    dec.setCreateBy(userId);
                    dec.setLastModDate(new Date());
                    dec.setLastModBy(userId);

                    vms032AhmgavmsDecsDao.update(dec);
                    vms032AhmgavmsDecsDao.flush();
                    return DtoHelper.constructResponseWorkspace(StatusMsgEnum.SUKSES, null, null);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: The main property of any primary table key is its uniqueness within the owning table. Your expressed intent with "having two rows with the same primary key" contradicts this property, so you can't do that. You can, however, have a composite primary key composed of several columns. Like discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585034/how-to-map-a-composite-key-with-jpa-and-hibernate), for example.