# Mapping multiple-row per item objects in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, composite-key, hibernate-annotations

I'm encountering somewhat of an, uh, unorthodox design and I'm not quite sure how to handle it. The table I'm trying to map looks like:

```
TABLE example {
    ID INT,
    CATEGORY VARCHAR,
    PROPERTY VARCHAR,
    VALUE VARCHAR);
```

A single id can have several rows (obviously, not a primary key). As an example, it could look like:

```
# ID  CATEGORY     PROPERTY VALUE
  1   general_info name     order 1
  1   general_info date     1/1/2009
  ...
```

Every ID might have several different categories for it. Property names are unique for any given (id, category) combination.

(EDIT) The ID field is a foreign key to objects in a different table. I need to be able to get from these objects to the various properties stored in this table, using only the ID field. If a composite key is the way to go, how do I then link them?

(EDIT2) I also think the detail you're missing here is that all the data with the same ID in column one conceptually belongs to the same object. I don't want a separate instance for every (ID,CATEGORY) combination.

Obviously, this isn't very normalized. Worst case scenario, I set up some extra tables that are normalized and copy everything over, but I was wondering if anyone could suggest a sensible way to get this information into hibernate backed objects directly? If necessary in some sort of bag of String properties.

I'm using hibernate-annotations btw.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to map a composite key with Hiberante?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585034/)

Comment: @PascalThivent thanks, I added some extra info. I don't think it's a straightforward composite key problem, but suggestions on how to make that work welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the ID is a foreign key to another table (let's call that table 'container'), this can be mapped as a Map with a composite key.

Example:

```
public class Container {
    private int id;
    private Map<Key,String> values = new HashMap<Key,String>();

    public String getValue(String category, String property) {
        return values.get(new Key(category, property));
    }

    public void setValue(String category, String property, String value) {
        values.put(new Key(category, property), value);
    }

    public static class Key {
        private String category;
        private String property;

        public Key(String cat, String prop) {
            category = cat;
            property = prop;
        }

        public String getCategory() {
            return category;
        }

        public String getProperty() {
            return property;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (!(obj instanceof Key)) {
                return false;
            }
            Key k = (Key)obj;
            return category.equals(k.category) && property.equals(k.property);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return 37*category.hashCode() + property.hashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

Mapping:

```
<class name="Container" table="container">
    <id column="ID" name="id">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <map cascade="all-delete-orphan" name="values" table="example">
        <key column="ID"/>
        <composite-map-key class="Container$Key">
            <key-property name="category" type="string" column="CATEGORY"/>
            <key-property name="property" type="string" column="PROPERTY"/>
        </composite-map-key>
        <element type="string" column="VALUE"/>
    </map>
</class>
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this might work with the latest hibernate-annotations but not with any JPA1 ones?

Comment: Thanks. I ended up avoiding collection of elements but doing something very similar mapping the property as a class with an embedded key and using `@OneToMany(mappedBy="key.id")`. Apparently subexpressions are legal and it seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

Use a composite key with ID, CATEGORY and PROPERTY. See [Multiple key in hibernate how to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585034/multiple-key-in-hibernate-how-to) and [JPA - Entity design problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562746/jpa-entity-design-problem) for examples on how to implements this (@EmbeddedId is the key!)