# Hibernate JPA uniqueness

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Let's say that this is a class that has unique constrained field.

```
@Entity
public class Thing {

   @Column(name = "name", unique = true)
   private String name;

   @ManyToOne
   private Owner owner;

}
```

Example works just fine if new `Things` are created with unique names. But when different owners want to create things with the same name this approach fails.

Is it possible to set unique constraint to differ records of `Things` in the database based on the `Owners` using Hibernate/JPA functionalities (I could not find any) or should I write my own logic and dump the `unique` from `@Column`.

Perhaps it could be done with Hibernate Validator? Reading the [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.3/reference/en-US/html_single/) I haven't found much about unique constraints.

Comment: I'm no Hibernate expert but in this question they deal with the same problem. Maybe this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562746/jpa-entity-design-problem/2563009#2563009

Comment: @RubioRic: interesting, I will examine it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for @UniqueConstraint

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/UniqueConstraint.html

Comment: I don't see how could suggested annotation perform differently. It's used to define multiple constraints at the table level rather than at column level. I need more like cross-table solution.

Comment: In your case, you don't want name to be unique, but the combination of name and owner to be unique. As it stands now, attempting to add a second thing with the same name as any existing thing will violate your one, column-level uniqueness constraint.

Comment: That makes more sense. So I could annotate `Thing` with something like `@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"owner_id", "name"})`?

Comment: It turns out that this really solves the problem. Answer accepted!